# Jar with dependencies not included in zip file with maven assembly plugin

Tags: java, maven

I am using maven assembly plugin to generate a zip file containing my jar including all dependencies, however the jar included does not contain all the jars when i use this command:

```
  jar tf jar-included-in-the-zip.jar
```

Here is my configuration:

```
 <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>my-jar</finalName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assembly-id</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier></classifier>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and here is my assembly:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">

<id>xxx</id>

<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>

<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${my-jar.target.dir}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${my-jar.ouput.dar.dir}/${version}</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

In target i get a jar containing all dependencies, and a zip containing a jar that does not include the dependencies. How can i get to include my jar with dependencies into the zip file.

Comment: I think the `id` element in your `assembly.xml` should match the `descriptorRef` in your `pom.xml`, i.e. `jar-with-dependencies`

Comment: Tried it, still my zip file doesn't contain the jar with dependencies.

Comment: Please show the full pom file... and not only excerpts..

Answer (score 0):

Try with this kind of configuration. I don't think whether you need `assembly.xml`. You can have all your dependencies as a part of your **jar** file itself if they are available on classpath. Is there any specific need for **zip** file in your case?

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>{your.package.name.MainClass}</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Yes zip is needed for deployment purpose. The deploy goal will look for the zip file to import it to nexus and other repos.

Comment: why can't you import `jar` file directly to nexus with your process?

Comment: I have a custom maven plugin for deploying to some repos and this plugin look up for zip file in target only.

Comment: repos are not necessary Nexus, it's deployment repos.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
<include>**/*.jar</include>
```

by

```
<include>*:jar:*</include>
```

in your *assembly.xml*